# WordPress URL Rewrite to pass name of studio

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a site http://hitplayyoga.com and we have a studio directory on that site. It lists all the studios in our system. We are writing the URL link to the studio like this right now:

```
http://hitplayyoga.com/studio-detail/69
```

and that will properly display the details for the studio with the ID of 69. We want to change the URL so that it includes the studio name. It should either be

```
http://hitplayyoga.com/studio-detail/69/3-Oms-Yoga
```

-or-

```
http://hitplayyoga.com/studio-detail/3-Oms-Yoga
```

How can I write a rule in .htaccess that will redirect the page to studio-detail/?id=$1&name=$2 if I include the ID or studio-detail/?name=$2 if I do not include the ID? I am a newbie at .htaccess files and rewrite rules. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the PHP file name that loads the the studio detail and in what folder it is? What is the current rule that you have on your `.htaccess` for `http://hitplayyoga.com/studio-detail/69`? Or are you using a directory plugin for WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep ID in the URL. This is the rule that should work for you:

```
RewriteRule ^(studio-detail)/([0-9]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/?id=$2&name=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: If you open this URL: `http://hitplayyoga.com/studio-detail/?id=69&name=3-Oms-Yoga` does it open properly?

Comment: I just tried opening `http://hitplayyoga.com/studio-detail/?id=69&name=3-Oms-Yoga` and got 404 error

Comment: Thanks...I get a 404 Not Found when using this rule. If I change the URL to be:

    <kbd>http://hitplayyoga.com/studio-detail/69</kbd>

I get a SQL syntax error in my script. When I then change the .htaccess rule to be:

    <kbd>RewriteRule ^studio-detail/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ studio-detail/?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA,NC]</kbd>

I get a 404 error when I include the studio name in the URL and I get the page correctly displayed if I leave the studio name out of the URL and only use the ID. Any ideas?

Comment: The thing is even this URL: `http://hitplayyoga.com/studio-detail/?id=69&name=3-Oms-Yoga` is generating 404 so there is something in your script (or WP). Since there is no mod_rewrite rule being used for this query string based URL.

Comment: What I've discovered is that whatever goes into the third part of the URL is treated as a search phrase. So <kbd>http://hitplayyoga.com/studiodetail/69/a<kbd> finds an about us page.

Comment: The thing is that even `http://hitplayyoga.com/studio-detail/?id=69&name=3-Oms-Yoga` is showing 404 error.

Comment: Also, if you go to <kbd>http://hitplayyoga.com/studio-detail/?id=69&something=3-Oms-Yoga</kbd> (changing "name" to "something") you get the page. However, changing the Rewrite rule to match doesn't work.

Comment: Yes which tells me that there is some WP trick involved here which unfortunately I won't be able to guess :(